# $(1+i)(e^{(1+i)\phi})$ expressed in polar and rectangular form

Tags: complex-numbers

$$(1+i)(e^{(1+i)\phi})$$

I need to express this in both polar and rectangular form, but the difficult part is that extra $i$ above the $e$. Also, what am I supposed to make of $\phi$? We normally use $\theta$ to represent the argument of a complex number, so would this just be another notation for the angle?

Would the final answer in rectangular form not have a $\phi$ in it?

Comment: $\phi$ probably just is alternative to $\theta$, if you have no other information given.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, $\phi$ is used to denote an angle, just as $\theta$ commonly is. It doesn't matter what variable we use. Although, $\phi$ or $\theta$ are commonly used we could just as easily use $x$ or $y$.

Now on to expanding your expression:

$$(1+i)(e^{(1+i)\phi}) = e^{(1+i)\phi}+ie^{(1+i)\phi}$$

Note that $e^{(1+i)\phi} = e^\phi e^{i\phi} = e^\phi [\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi) ]$

**Edit:**

Here is some more info for you to consider.
$$(1+i)(e^{(1+i)\phi}) = e^{(1+i)\phi}+ie^{(1+i)\phi}$$
$$ = e^\phi(\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi))+e^\phi(-\sin(\phi)+i\cos(\phi))$$

Noting that $-\sin(\phi)= \cos(\phi+\frac\pi2)$ and $\cos(\phi)=\sin(\phi +\frac\pi2)$ we can further simplify the above expression. So,

$$e^\phi(\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi))+e^\phi(-\sin(\phi)+i\cos(\phi))= $$

$$e^\phi(\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi))+e^\phi(\cos(\phi+\frac\pi2)+i\sin(\phi+\frac\pi2))$$

Written in this form you can see that your original expression is the sum of two complex numbers with a phase angle difference of $\frac\pi2$, that both have the same magnitude, namely $e^\phi$. To actually write this in terms of cartesian coordinates in any easy way, I believe (I may be wrong) that actual values of $\phi$ would be helpful. Otherwise, refer to this blerb from wikipedia:

[image]

I hope this is not too confusing.

Comment: I got as far as $e^{\phi}(cos(\phi)+isin(\phi)+icos(\phi)-sin(\phi))$...

Comment: Could you possibly help me out a bit more?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat 1. "*To actually write this in terms of cartesian coordinates in any easy way, actual values of ϕ would be helpful.*" I think allen means "To actually write this in **polar form**...", and indeed the expression's [argument](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Arg%28%281%2Bi%29%28e%5E%7B%281%2Bi%29phi%7D%29%29) isn't easy to write.$\quad$2. Notice that the Cartesian/rectangular form has already been found, via Euler's formula, in the Edit's first paragraph.